# Unable to test send and receive SMS with Android Studio 2.1.1 emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, sms, android-studio-2.1

I'm trying to test an application that sends a SMS automatically, and I want to test this functionality with the emulator to avoid SMS costs.

In order to do so, I started two emulators and used the port as the phone number to send the SMS from one emulator to the other, like I've read in other questions here in SO (and like I've done successfully some years ago, if I remember correctly).

The fact is that I'm not able to see any received SMS in the second emulator. To be sure that there isn't a problem with my implementation, I tried also to send a SMS using the Messaging app installed by default in the emulator, but with the same result.

I'm using Android Studio 2.1.1 and I've tried different emulator configurations, using Android 4.4, Android 5.1 and Android 6.0, all with Google APIs.

Am I missing something? There's some configuration to be modified in order to send and receive SMS in the emulator? There's another way to test SMS sending without costs?

Comment: I've answered this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38049670/send-sms-between-android-emulators/38121938#38121938
It's a known bug, hope they fix it soon...