# Send SMS between Android emulators

Tags: android, android-emulator

Before Android Studio 2.0, I could send SMS messages between emulators using their emulator ids (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4726121/212508). However this method is not working on new emulators with the panel on the right side.

Is it possible to send SMS messages between new Android Emulators(2.x)?

Note: I want to send the message from emulator to emulator. Not through telnet or ADM.

Answer (score 7):

I'm facing the same problem. It looks that it is a known bug, you can find it here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=210767

Looks like they have solved it, and will add the fix on future versions.

Meanwhile I haven't found any way to solve it...

Comment: Well if there is no solution to the problem you should get the bounty.

Comment: Yes, finally it is solved upgrading to latest Preview Android SDK Build Tools

Answer (score 1):

Write this code and run application in Emulator 5554.

```
PendingIntent pi;
SmsManager sms;
String msg = "android.telephony.SmsManager.STATUS_ON_ICC_SENT";
PendingIntent piSent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0,new Intent(msg), 0);
sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendTextMessage("5556", null, "This is sample test message", piSent, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ugrading to the most recent Preview Android SDK Build Tools solves the problem.

> Android SDK Tools 25.2.2 rc1

[image]

Be sure to enable "Preview Tools" in the settigns.